# A general formulation of least squares

Tags: least-squares

I am confused about  of writing the formulation using linear least squares ,there is references writing it such as :

$$ ||Ax-b ||^2_2$$
and other references such as :
$$ ||b-Ax ||^2_2$$
What is meant by each formulation?and when to use ?

Comment: Which is a requirement for any norm.

Comment: @David, You should write this as an answer so the question will be marked as solved.

Comment: @Royi OK, done.

Answer (score 1):

They are totally identical since $\|{\bf v}\|=\|{-\bf v}\|$.  It doesn't make any difference which you use.